# Random cell reference for gspread?

Tags: python, arrays, gspread

I'm trying to figure out how to create a random number generator that links between gspread API for a google sheet cell reference and the random library in python.

```
import gspread
import random

sheet = gc.open_by_key('*insert key*')
worksheet = sheet.sheet1

randomlist = [worksheet.length]
   for i in range(0, randomlist.length()):
   position = random.randint(1, i)
   randomlist.append(n)
```

I've tried multiple ways but none seem to get me the reference of a random cell within a google sheet reference for the first column. Really stuck here and could use some help.

I get this error as my code isn't correct and I'm just really lost.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    randomlist = [worksheet.length]
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'length'
```

Comment: What value do you want to retrieve with `randomlist = [worksheet.length]`?

Comment: the length of the column essentially like within an array

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
`worksheet.get_all_values()` as a substitute. This will return all of the values in your sheet as a list containing different lists. e.g. `[row1, row2, row3 ...]` with `row1=["a","b","g", ...]`

API Reference : https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-worksheet-as-a-list-of-lists